# How to move to page anchor only after page has fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, anchor

I'm trying to use page anchors on my website, but having issues because content is dynamically loaded from JSON and therefore page anchors are triggering before the content is drawn and fully loaded.

Using Javascript I'd like to move to the page anchor only after all the content on the page has been loaded and drawn. I've found a few solutions on StackOverflow but they all rely on JQuery which I'm trying to avoid. How would you do this in vanilla Javascript?

JQuery examples:

- [Load anchor tag after page has fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284027/load-anchor-tag-after-page-has-fully-loaded)
- [How to disable anchor jump when loading a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096621/how-to-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Not enough info. Are you already on the page? Are you coming from another page? How is the page loading, why is the anchor not there? How are you trying to get to the anchor now? What is the problem now? Etc. Don't answer as a comment, update your question. Include all code you have tried and the HTML.